# SMB connection time-out on enterprise VPN

Tags: vpn, network-shares, smb

osx 10.15.7

While successfully connected to my University's VPN (Paolo Alto GlobalProtect client), I am unable to connect (timeout) to my department's SMB network share from my home workstation. I have verified that both local smb client and the server seem to be working (more detailed description below).

This is a NEW problem, meaning I was using the same vpn client and local machine without issue until a few weeks ago, and I'm unaware of any config changes or updates that may have caused this. I am at the end of my troubleshooting ability, and my university IT has been less than helpful, though this does seem to be a local issue.

**Troubleshooting and additional details:**

- I am able to connect to the university VPN successfully (tunnel sets up, assigned university IP address)
- I am able to access other local shares on my home network (when not connected to vpn tun)
- Timeout occurs regardless of connection method, via finder (Command+K) or using mount_smbfs
- (The kicker) **I am able to access the share in question on other machines** (windows, linux, osx) using the same Global Connect client, with the same user credentials, from the same home network as my main workstation.

monitoring console and tcpdump haven't provided anything else useful insofar as I can interpret the output.

```
default 13:47:24.239991-0600    NetAuthSysAgent quarantine check returned 1
default 13:47:24.241894-0600    NetAuthSysAgent Mount URL: request CDA921BB-A292-41FF-B80A-D425F9167CAE from Finder (707)
default 13:47:24.243098-0600    NetAuthSysAgent URL = smb://<SHAREPATH>
default 13:47:24.245114-0600    NetAuthSysAgent Session created
default 13:48:45.379162-0600    NetAuthSysAgent GetServerInfo failed 60
```

Lastly, there are few perplexing things:
My university also allows Cisco AnyConnect client, using this I AM able to access the share. However this is not acceptable solution, as there are a slew of other network issues i experience upon disconnect when using this client, and ultimately our university is planning to consolidate all the vpns under globalprotect anyways in the near future.

reinstalling client has not solved the issue. Curiously, I was still unable to access the share even in a virtual windows machine (on my workstation) that was connected to the vpn.

Ideas on next steps greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure that both VPN systems assign you to the same subnet ice you are logged in? May be the university's VPN does not allow access to internal servers of your department? Ask the VPN admins if there was a policy or config change recently.

Comment: @Robert Robert, both VPN clients (Anyconnect and GlobalProtect) provide different subnets, though this is by design. The VPN subnet doesn't seem to be the issue, as other machines that i've tested this don't care which client i use when accessing and mounting the share, my department's share is accessible either way, just not from this one machine for some reason (when using GlobalProtect). I will try with IT and VPN admins again.

Answer (score 0):

Issue lies with the Private Internet Access Daemon and split tunneling (most likely).

Quitting and turning off the daemon (which apparently still runs even if the PIA app itself is not connected or running), allowed me to connect to the share drive through while on my University's GlobalProtect VPN.